# highlight a current date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I am beginner for programming. I got a code from online and I am modifying to get hands on js, jquery, jsp. What I am trying to get is I need to highlight a today's date. I tried many times but could not succeeded. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 var Calendar = function(calen) {
    //Store div id
    this.divId = calen.ParentID;
    // Days of week, starting on Sunday
    this.DaysOfWeek = calen.DaysOfWeek;
    // Months, stating on January
    this.Months = calen.Months;

    // Set the current month, year
    var d = new Date();
    this.CurrentMonth = d.getMonth();
    this.CurrentYear = d.getFullYear();
    

    var f=calen.Format;
    //this.f = typeof(f) == 'string' ? f.charAt(0).toUpperCase() : 'M';

    if(typeof(f) == 'string') {
      this.f  = f.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
    } else {
      this.f = 'M';
    }

  };

  // Goes to next month
  Calendar.prototype.nextMonth = function() {

    if ( this.CurrentMonth == 11 ) {

      this.CurrentMonth = 0;
      
      this.CurrentYear++;

    } else {
      console.log("this.CurrentMonth == ", this.CurrentMonth);
      this.CurrentMonth++;
    }

    this.showCurrent();
  };

  // Goes to previous month
  Calendar.prototype.previousMonth = function() {

    if ( this.CurrentMonth == 0 ) {

      this.CurrentMonth = 11;
      this.CurrentYear--;

    } else {

      this.CurrentMonth--;

    }

    this.showCurrent();
  };

  // 
  Calendar.prototype.previousYear = function() {
    this.CurrentYear--;
    this.showCurrent();
  }
 
  Calendar.prototype.nextYear = function() {

    this.CurrentYear++;

    this.showCurrent();
  }              

  // Show current month
  Calendar.prototype.showCurrent = function() {
   
    this.Calendar(this.CurrentYear, this.CurrentMonth);
    
  };
  
  

  // Show month (year, month)
  Calendar.prototype.Calendar = function(y,m,n) {
    
    typeof(y) == 'number' ? this.CurrentYear = y : null;
    typeof(y) == 'number' ? this.CurrentMonth = m : null;
    typeof(y) == 'number' ? this.CurrDate = n : null;


    // 1st day of the selected month
    var firstDayOfCurrentMonth = new Date(y, m, 1).getDay();
    
    // Last date of the selected month
    var lastDateOfCurrentMonth = new Date(y, m+1, 0).getDate();

    // Last day of the previous month
    var lastDateOfLastMonth = m == 0 ? new Date(y-1, 11, 0).getDate() : new Date(y, m, 0).getDate();

    
    // Write selected month and year. This HTML goes into <div id="year"></div>
    //var yearhtml = '<span class="yearspan">' + y + '</span>';

    // Write selected month and year. This HTML goes into <div id="month"></div>
    //var monthhtml = '<span class="monthspan">' + this.Months[m] + '</span>';

    // Write selected month and year. This HTML goes into <div id="month"></div>
    var monthandyearhtml = '<span id="monthandyearspan">' + this.Months[m] + ' - ' + y + '</span>';

    var html = '<table>';

    // Write the header of the days of the week
    html += '<tr>';

    
    for(var i=0; i < 7;i++) {


      html += '<th class="daysheader">' + this.DaysOfWeek[i] + '</th>';
    }

    html += '</tr>';


    //this.f = 'X';

    var p = dm = this.f == 'M' ? 1 : (firstDayOfCurrentMonth == 0 ? -5 : 2);

    
    
    var cellvalue;

    for (var d, i=0, z=0; z<6; z++) {
      html += '<tr>';

      for (var k= 0; k < 7; k++) {
        d = i + dm - firstDayOfCurrentMonth;

        // Dates from prev month
        if (d < 1){
          cellvalue = lastDateOfLastMonth - firstDayOfCurrentMonth + p++;
          
          html += '<td id="prevmonthdates">' + 
                '<span id="cellvaluespan">' + (cellvalue) + '</span><br/>' + 
             
              '</td>';

        // Dates from next month
        } else if ( d > lastDateOfCurrentMonth){
         
         html += '<td id="nextmonthdates">' + (p++) + '</td>';

        // Current month dates
          
        } else {
          html += '<td id="currentmonthdates">' + (d) + '</td>';
          p = 1;
        }
        
        
        if (i % 7 == 6 && d >= lastDateOfCurrentMonth) {

          z = 10; // no more rows
        }


        i++;

      }

      html += '</tr>';
    }

    // Closes table
    html += '</table>';

    
    document.getElementById("monthandyear").innerHTML = monthandyearhtml;

    document.getElementById(this.divId).innerHTML = html;
  };

  // On Load of the window
  window.onload = function() {
    
    // Start calendar
    var c = new Calendar({
      ParentID:"divcalendartable",

      DaysOfWeek:[
      'MON',
      'TUE',
      'WED',
      'THU',
      'FRI',
      'SAT',
      'SUN'
      ],

      Months:['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec' ],

      Format:'dd/mm/yyyy'
    });
    
   

    c.showCurrent();
    
    
    // Bind next and previous button clicks
    getId('btnPrev').onclick = function(){
      c.previousMonth();
    };

    getId('btnPrevYr').onclick = function(){
      c.previousYear();
    };

    getId('btnNext').onclick = function(){
      c.nextMonth();
    };

    getId('btnNextYr').onclick = function(){
      c.nextYear();
    };                        
  }

  // Get element by id
  function getId(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
  }

});
```

```css
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: Georgia, Times, serif;
}

th {
  border: 1px solid #A8A8A8;
  vertical-align: top;
}

td {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #A8A8A8;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align:center;
}

.divcalendar {
  padding: 15px;
    float:left;
    /*background-color: #FFCC00;*/
}

/* Wrapper div. That makes the inner div into an inline element that can be centered with text-align.*/
#calendaroverallcontrols {
  text-align: center;
}

/* This is a fluid div as width will be changing */
#calendarmonthcontrols {
  display: inline-block;
  /*background-color: #FF0000;*/
}

#calendarmonthcontrols > div, #calendarmonthcontrols > a {
    display: inline-block;
}    

#btnPrevYr {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 35px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /*background: #00FFCC;*/      
}

#btnPrev {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /*background: #00FFCC;*/
}    

/*.yearspan {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.monthspan {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}*/

#monthandyearspan {
  width: 50px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /*background: #00FFCC;*/
}    

#monthandyear {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#btnNext {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /*background: #00FFCC;*/
}

#btnNextYr {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 35px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /*background: #00FFCC;*/
}        

#divcalendartable {
  clear: both;
}

.daysheader {
  background: #C0C0C0;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#prevmonthdates {
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

#nextmonthdates {
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

#currentmonthdates {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

#cellvaluespan {
  background: #FF0000;
}

#cellvaluelist {
  background: #FFCC00;
}        

.swim {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  background: #445511;
  color: #F5F5F5;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.chrono {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  background: #778899;
  color: #F5F5F5;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<div class="divcalendar">

<div id="calendaroverallcontrols">

  <div id="calendarmonthcontrols">
     <a id="btnPrevYr" href="#" title="Previous Year"><span></span></a> 

    <a id="btnPrev" href="#" title="Previous Month"><span><</span></a>
  
  
    

    <div id="monthandyear"></div>


    <a id="btnNext" href="#" title="Next Month"><span>></span></a>

  <a id="btnNextYr" href="#" title="Next Year"><span></span></a>      
  </div>
</div>

<!-- extra  -->
<div id="divcalendartable"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduction:  you don't need at all jQuery.  Avoid to insert into jQuery Dom ready event the window.onload. It's useless.

The fast way to achieve your goal is:

**Define a new css class**:

```
.currentDay {

     background-color: green !important;
}
```

**In the method "Calendar.prototype.Calendar = function (y, m, n) {" change these lines:**

```
// Current month dates

} else {
    html += '<td id="currentmonthdates">' + (d) + '</td>';
    p = 1;
}
```

with:

```
} else {
    var lDate = new Date();
    if (d == lDate.getDate() && this.CurrentMonth == lDate.getMonth() &&
         this.CurrentYear == lDate.getFullYear()) {
        html += '<td id="currentmonthdates" class="currentDay">' + (d) + '</td>';
    } else {
        html += '<td id="currentmonthdates">' + (d) + '</td>';
    }
    p = 1;
}
```

The previous change adds the class **currentDay** to today.

```js
var Calendar = function (calen) {
    //Store div id
    this.divId = calen.ParentID;
    // Days of week, starting on Sunday
    this.DaysOfWeek = calen.DaysOfWeek;
    // Months, stating on January
    this.Months = calen.Months;
    // Set the current month, year
    var d = new Date();
    this.CurrentMonth = d.getMonth();
    this.CurrentYear = d.getFullYear();
    var f = calen.Format;
    //this.f = typeof(f) == 'string' ? f.charAt(0).toUpperCase() : 'M';
    if (typeof(f) == 'string') {
        this.f = f.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
    } else {
        this.f = 'M';
    }
};
// Goes to next month
Calendar.prototype.nextMonth = function () {
    if (this.CurrentMonth == 11) {
        this.CurrentMonth = 0;
        this.CurrentYear++;
    } else {
        console.log("this.CurrentMonth == ", this.CurrentMonth);
        this.CurrentMonth++;
    }
    this.showCurrent();
};
// Goes to previous month
Calendar.prototype.previousMonth = function () {
    if (this.CurrentMonth == 0) {
        this.CurrentMonth = 11;
        this.CurrentYear--;
    } else {
        this.CurrentMonth--;
    }
    this.showCurrent();
};
Calendar.prototype.previousYear = function () {
    this.CurrentYear--;
    this.showCurrent();
}
Calendar.prototype.nextYear = function () {
    this.CurrentYear++;
    this.showCurrent();
}
// Show current month
Calendar.prototype.showCurrent = function () {
    this.Calendar(this.CurrentYear, this.CurrentMonth);
};
// Show month (year, month)
Calendar.prototype.Calendar = function (y, m, n) {
    typeof(y) == 'number' ? this.CurrentYear = y : null;
    typeof(y) == 'number' ? this.CurrentMonth = m : null;
    typeof(y) == 'number' ? this.CurrDate = n : null;
    // 1st day of the selected month
    var firstDayOfCurrentMonth = new Date(y, m, 1).getDay();
    // Last date of the selected month
    var lastDateOfCurrentMonth = new Date(y, m + 1, 0).getDate();
    // Last day of the previous month
    var lastDateOfLastMonth = m == 0 ? new Date(y - 1, 11, 0).getDate() : new Date(y, m, 0).getDate();
    // Write selected month and year. This HTML goes into <div id="year"></div>
    //var yearhtml = '<span class="yearspan">' + y + '</span>';
    // Write selected month and year. This HTML goes into <div id="month"></div>
    //var monthhtml = '<span class="monthspan">' + this.Months[m] + '</span>';
    // Write selected month and year. This HTML goes into <div id="month"></div>
    var monthandyearhtml = '<span id="monthandyearspan">' + this.Months[m] + ' - ' + y + '</span>';
    var html = '<table>';
    // Write the header of the days of the week
    html += '<tr>';
    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        html += '<th class="daysheader">' + this.DaysOfWeek[i] + '</th>';
    }
    html += '</tr>';
    //this.f = 'X';
    var p = dm = this.f == 'M' ? 1 : (firstDayOfCurrentMonth == 0 ? -5 : 2);
    var cellvalue;
    for (var d, i = 0, z = 0; z < 6; z++) {
        html += '<tr>';
        for (var k = 0; k < 7; k++) {
            d = i + dm - firstDayOfCurrentMonth;
            // Dates from prev month
            if (d < 1) {
                cellvalue = lastDateOfLastMonth - firstDayOfCurrentMonth + p++;
                html += '<td id="prevmonthdates">' +
                        '<span id="cellvaluespan">' + (cellvalue) + '</span><br/>' +
                        '</td>';
                // Dates from next month
            } else if (d > lastDateOfCurrentMonth) {
                html += '<td id="nextmonthdates">' + (p++) + '</td>';
                // Current month dates
            } else {
                var lDate = new Date();
                if (d == lDate.getDate() && this.CurrentMonth == lDate.getMonth() && this.CurrentYear == lDate.getFullYear()) {
                    html += '<td id="currentmonthdates" class="currentDay">' + (d) + '</td>';
                } else {
                    html += '<td id="currentmonthdates">' + (d) + '</td>';
                }
                p = 1;
            }
            if (i % 7 == 6 && d >= lastDateOfCurrentMonth) {
                z = 10; // no more rows
            }
            i++;
        }
        html += '</tr>';
    }
    // Closes table
    html += '</table>';
    document.getElementById("monthandyear").innerHTML = monthandyearhtml;
    document.getElementById(this.divId).innerHTML = html;
};
// On Load of the window
window.onload = function () {
    // Start calendar
    var c = new Calendar({
        ParentID: "divcalendartable",
        DaysOfWeek: [
            'MON',
            'TUE',
            'WED',
            'THU',
            'FRI',
            'SAT',
            'SUN'
        ],
        Months: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        Format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
    });
    c.showCurrent();
    // Bind next and previous button clicks
    getId('btnPrev').onclick = function () {
        c.previousMonth();
    };
    getId('btnPrevYr').onclick = function () {
        c.previousYear();
    };
    getId('btnNext').onclick = function () {
        c.nextMonth();
    };
    getId('btnNextYr').onclick = function () {
        c.nextYear();
    };
    // Get element by id
    function getId(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }
}
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-family: Georgia, Times, serif;
}

th {
    border: 1px solid #A8A8A8;
    vertical-align: top;
}

td {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #A8A8A8;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: center;
}

.divcalendar {
    padding: 15px;
    float: left;
    /*background-color: #FFCC00;*/
}

/* Wrapper div. That makes the inner div into an inline element that can be centered with text-align.*/
#calendaroverallcontrols {
    text-align: center;
}

/* This is a fluid div as width will be changing */
#calendarmonthcontrols {
    display: inline-block;
    /*background-color: #FF0000;*/
}

#calendarmonthcontrols > div, #calendarmonthcontrols > a {
    display: inline-block;
}

#btnPrevYr {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 35px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    /*background: #00FFCC;*/
}

#btnPrev {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 35px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    /*background: #00FFCC;*/
}

/*.yearspan {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.monthspan {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}*/

#monthandyearspan {
    width: 50px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    /*background: #00FFCC;*/
}

#monthandyear {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#btnNext {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 35px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    /*background: #00FFCC;*/
}

#btnNextYr {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 35px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    /*background: #00FFCC;*/
}

#divcalendartable {
    clear: both;
}

.daysheader {
    background: #C0C0C0;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#prevmonthdates {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

#nextmonthdates {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

#currentmonthdates {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

#cellvaluespan {
    background: #FF0000;
}

#cellvaluelist {
    background: #FFCC00;
}

.swim {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: center;
    background: #445511;
    color: #F5F5F5;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.chrono {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: center;
    background: #778899;
    color: #F5F5F5;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
.currentDay {
    background-color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="divcalendar">

    <div id="calendaroverallcontrols">

        <div id="calendarmonthcontrols">
            <a id="btnPrevYr" href="#" title="Previous Year"><span></span></a>

            <a id="btnPrev" href="#" title="Previous Month"><span><</span></a>


            <div id="monthandyear"></div>


            <a id="btnNext" href="#" title="Next Month"><span>></span></a>

            <a id="btnNextYr" href="#" title="Next Year"><span></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- extra  -->
    <div id="divcalendartable"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you sir thank you very much for your effective answer. It worked perfect. I got a small question on CSS what's the reason for using "!important" after green: when I remove "!important" it does not highlights the current date.

Comment: Important means it has priority on the default value (see currentmonthdates in your css). Take a look to "MDN css important"

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to include jQuery.js.

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/